# PhoneGap plugins won't load

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to build a PhoneGap app for android. I need to use the Sqlite plugin.
According to [PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/configuring_plugins.md.html#importing-native) I need to declare the plugins in `config.xml` and I'll be good to go but I'm not. It just won't work.

I'm using the Sqlite plugin this way:

```
window.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my_db"});
```

The `sqlitePlugin` is undefined. I'm using the following plugins as well, so if anything's worth noting, please share them with me.

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.sqlite" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
```

**Edit:** One important question. Do I need to include the plugins js file in my `index.html` using the `script` tag?

Answer (score 1):

The line I see for sqlite plugin in [the phonegap build plugins repository](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins) is

```
<gap:plugin name="ch.zhaw.sqlite" version="2.0.0" />
```

Does it work better if you replace the line in config.xml?

Comment: No success my friend. I couldn't install the plugin you said.

Comment: My bad, the doc for the plugin says it's Windows 8 only :(

Comment: From this link, it seems that Sqliteplugin has never grone through the phonegap build submission. http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how_to_add_sqlite_plugin_to_phonegap_build_for_iphone_and_androin There's also a post about this in the forum of the plugin but no news since last year.

Comment: I don't use phonegap build anymore, but there are now several sqlite plugins listed when you do a search in https://build.phonegap.com/plugins. The one I use with Cordova is this one : https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/2368